# Remove comments following # (number sign) in shell

Tags: bash

I have a text file `text0.txt` like

```
# text0.txt
# This is comment
Hello, I like banana.  # more comments
bra bra bra...
```

The question is what is the command

```
$ some_command text0.txt
```

which outputs

```
Hello, I like banana.  
bra bra bra...
```

to standard output.

I'm using bash.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you make any attempt to research this yourself?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Actually, it solves the problem. I didn't have an idea to use sed and I couldn't search "#" as a key word.

Comment: I just searched `remove comments bash` on google.

Answer (score 2):

You want to delete lines that start with a `#` and to remove a `#` and any following characters anywhere else on a line.  That description practically defines what the `sed` script should look like:

```
sed -e '/^#/d' -e 's/[[:space:]]*#.*//' text0.txt
```

This removes any spaces before the `#` at the end of a line too.  You could combine that into one argument if you insist:

```
sed '/^#/d; s/[[:space:]]*#.*//' text0.txt
```

Personally, I think it's easier to read the separate operations when they're in separate arguments, but that's a choice you can make for yourself.

Note that there is no need to run two (or more) commands; one is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

with awk:

```
awk '{a=length($0);gsub("#.*","",$0); if(a==0 || length($0)>0)print $0}' filename
```